# Encoding JSON in r

Tags: json, r, encoding

How to change the encoding when using the JSON package in R?

```
for (pageNum in 0:20) {
  data <- fromJSON(paste0("https://api.hh.ru/vacancies?text=\"бухгалтер\"&page=", pageNum))
  vacanciesdf <- rbind(vacanciesdf, data.frame(
    data$items$area$name, 
    data$items$salary$currency, 
    data$items$salary$from, 
    data$items$employer$name,
    data$items$name,
    data$items$snippet$requirement))
  print(paste0("Upload pages:", pageNum + 1))
  Sys.sleep(3)
}
```

In English, downloading from the API at the introduction of the keyword works, but nothing is loaded in Russian. I assume that the problem is in the encoding. But how to install UTF-8?

Answer (score 5):

These kinds of problems are hard to reproduce, but using 'content GET' to apply UTF-8 encoding, before the 'fromJSON' often resolves the problem.

The URL provided in your question returns an error, so this solution demonstrates the principal, getting the argument list from the api you are using.

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

URL <- "https://api.hh.ru/vacancies?describe_arguments=true"
text <- content(GET(URL), as = "text", encoding = "UTF-8")
data <- fromJSON(text)
```

This returns UTF-8 encoded JSON.

Comment: thanks, but error:

<pre>
> data <- content(GET(paste0("https://api.hh.ru/vacancies?text=\"бухгалтер\"&page=", pageNum),as = "text", encoding = "UTF-8"))
> data <- fromJSON(text)

Error: Argument 'txt' must be a JSON string, URL or file.
</pre>

Comment: seems to be a problem with the link itself.  when entered into a browser, I get this error message:

Comment: Did a little more investigating.  The core issue seems to be maintaining the correct hybrid encoding in the outbound URL, following the paste0.  What is your system's default encoding?  you can find this with:  Sys.getlocale(category = "LC_CTYPE")